# Problem with pst-dbicons examples

Tags: pstricks

I am currently trying to get the example of the [pstricks dbicons](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-dbicons/) package to work but I always end up with errors.

I have tried to compile the mondial example (see dbicons-site, sorry i can only put in 2 hyperlinks) but also the much shorter example from the pdf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-coil,color,pst-dbicons}
\seticonparams{entity}{shadow=true,fillcolor=black!30,fillstyle=solid}
\seticonparams{attribute}{fillcolor=black!10,fillstyle=solid}
\seticonparams{relationship} shadow=true,fillcolor=black!20,fillstyle=solid}

\begin{document}
\entity{Person}
\attributeof{Person}{30}[key]{Name}
\attributeof{Person}{90}[mv]{Nickname}
\attributeof{Person}[4em]{150}{phone}[phone\_no]
\attributeof{Person}{270}[mv]{wt}[weight\_at]
\attributeof{wt}{220}{date}
\attributeof{wt}{300}{weight}

\end{document}
```

Here are the gists for  [the mondial one](https://gist.github.com/856437) and the small one with gist id 856439.

I'd be delighted if someone could point out my error(s).

Comment: Note that it is unusual around here to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to have any greeting.

Answer (score 3):

Your system seems really out of date. You'll find up-to-date versions here: http://texnik.dante.de

However, your example has an error! With this one I get the attached output

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-dbicons}
\seticonparams{entity}{shadow=true,fillcolor=black!30,fillstyle=solid}
\seticonparams{attribute}{fillcolor=black!10,fillstyle=solid}
\seticonparams{relationship}{shadow=true,fillcolor=black!20,fillstyle=solid}

\begin{document}
\entity{Person}
\attributeof{Person}{30}[key]{Name}
\attributeof{Person}{90}[mv]{Nickname}
\attributeof{Person}[4em]{150}{phone}[phone\_no]
\attributeof{Person}{270}[mv]{wt}[weight\_at]
\attributeof{wt}{220}{date}
\attributeof{wt}{300}{weight}

\end{document}
```

[image]